# read from firebase realtime database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've implemented firebase realtime database in my project, what I want to do is to read from that database with swift's `Codable` I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to work because it prints `Fetched messages: []` empty string

```
database.child("\(id)").observe(.value) { snapshot in
    guard let messagesSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "messages").children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
        return
    }
    print(snapshot)
    
    var messages: [Meessage] = []
    for messageSnapshot in messagesSnapshot {
        guard let messageData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: messageSnapshot.value, options: []),
              var message = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Meessage.self, from: messageData) else {
            continue
        }
        //message.date = dateFormatter.date(from: message.dateString) ?? Date()
        message.date = Date()
        messages.append(message)
    }
    
    print("Fetched messages: \(messages)")
}
```

after printing `snapshot` I get snap below

```
Snap (conversation_leo-mail-ru_leo-mail-ru_Mar 3, 2023 at 11:35:34 PM GMT+4) {
    messages =     {
        0 =         {
            content = Testete;
            date = "Mar 3, 2023 at 11:35:34 PM GMT+4";
            id = "leo-mail-ru_leo-mail-ru_Mar 3, 2023 at 11:35:34 PM GMT+4";
            "is_read" = 0;
            name = leonti;
            "sender_email" = "leo@mail.ru";
            type = text;
        };
    };
}
```

I don't understand what the problem can be here's the model

```swift
struct Meessage: Codable {
    var content: String
    var date: Date
    var id: String
    var isRead: Bool
    var name: String
    var senderEmail: String
    var type: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case content
        case date
        case id
        case isRead = "is_read"
        case name
        case senderEmail = "sender_email"
        case type
    }
}
```

after printing `messageSnapshot` I get:

```json
Snap (0) {
    content = Testete;
    date = "Mar 3, 2023 at 11:35:34 PM GMT+4";
    id = "leo-mail-ru_leo-mail-ru_Mar 3, 2023 at 11:35:34 PM GMT+4";
    "is_read" = 0;
    name = leonti;
    "sender_email" = "leo@mail.ru";
    type = text;
}
```

Comment: I find the `messages` key in your print output somewhat unexpected, based on experience with other platforms. Can you also print `messageSnapshot` inside the loop and show the updated code and its output in your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Edited the question, can you check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `JSONDecoder` on the value you get back from `messageSnapshot.value`, but `messageSnapshot.value` doesn't return a JSON object. See the reference docs of [`DataSnapshot.value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value) to see what types it *does* return.

This unfortunately means that you can't use a `Codable` for getting Swift object from a `DataSnapshot`. It sounds like a reasonable wish though, so I recommend filing a feature request for it on the [SKD repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk).

---

**Update**: I have have been wrong about that, as this article shows how to [read Codable objects from Realtime Database](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-use-codable-in-firebase-realtime-database-60d6299369f1).

Comment: on exactly which type is can't be returned, date I guess ?